# Non-working htaccess Rewriterule to match end of URL

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to write an .htaccess rule redirecting all URLs ending in `Fizzle/xxxx_showabstract` (where `xxxx` can be an arbitrary string).  The rule I wrote is:

```
RewriteRule .*/Fizzle/(.*)_showabstract$ /abstractdisplay.php?journal=Fizzle&article=$1
```

But this, simple and straightforward though it to me, doesn't appear to be matching the intended URLs.  What am I doing wrong?  All help will be profoundly appreciated.

Comment: What kinds of characters are allowed in the arbitrary xxxxx? As you have it, it would match things like `Fizzle/other/dir/_showabstract`, which I don't think you want.

Comment: Also please post an example of what it is matching now, that it should not match (plus any other rewrite rules you have defined)

Comment: No, I definitely wouldn't want it to match the example you give, so my (.*) needs further restriction.  The problem, however, is not that my pattern matches to much, but that it doesn't match anything at all (i.e. Apache seems to omit it and go on to subsequent patters).  And you know what?  I am now realizing that this seems to be a problem with the MAMP Apache running on my Mac; the same pattern on my Unix server works just fine!

Comment: Well I notice that you don't have `[L]` where you should at the end of that rule. Make sure you have `RewriteEngine On`.

Answer (score 0):

This may work.

```
RewriteRule ^.*/Fizzle/([^/]*)_showabstract$ /abstractdisplay.php?journal=Fizzle&article=$1 [L]
```

The issue you're having may be caused by a certain order on executing the regex. But if you use the `^` it will match a complete URL only.